# Positioning multiple widgets in a BoxLayout in Kivy.

Tags: python, kivy

I have two widgets in a horizontal boxlayout. Afaik they will both stretch to fill half of the boxlayout. How do I go about resizing the widgets and repositioning within the boxlayout? Is it worth putting each widget in its own boxlayout so that it isn't affected by the widget beside it? Here is my code so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class ShoppingListScreen(Screen):
    pass

class theScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

theScreenManager:
    ShoppingListScreen:

<ShoppingListScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .3
            Button:
                text: '<'
                size_hint: .1, 1
                font_size: 75
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main' 

            Label:
                text: 'Login'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            Widget:
                size_hint: .1, 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                padding_left: 250
                Label:
                    text: 'Username:'
                    font_size: 25
                    color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                    size_hint: .2, .5
                    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                TextInput:
                    size_hint: .3, .1
        Button:
            text: 'Register'
            font_size: 35
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
            #on_release: app.root.current = 'main' 

        Label:
            text: 'Support'
            color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
            halign: 'left'
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 1, .3
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size


''')

class temprecipeapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    temprecipeapp().run()
```

If you run this file you will see the username and textinput box are in skewered positions. I am trying to center them and put them both beside each other. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
I just import GridLayout and change part with Label:Usename and TextInput from BoxLayout to GridLayout.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class ShoppingListScreen(Screen):
    pass

class theScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

theScreenManager:
    ShoppingListScreen:

<ShoppingListScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .3
            Button:
                text: '<'
                size_hint: .1, 1
                font_size: 75
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main' 

            Label:
                text: 'Login'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            Widget:
                size_hint: .1, 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            size_hint: 1, .1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size            

            Label:
                text: 'Username:'
                font_size: 25
                size_hint: .3, 1
                color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1             
                pos_hint: {'center': 1}

            TextInput:
                size_hint: .7, 1
                font_size: 25
        Button:
            text: 'Register'
            font_size: 35
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_normal: ""
            background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
            #on_release: app.root.current = 'main' 

        Label:
            text: 'Support'
            color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
            halign: 'left'
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 1, .3
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size


''')

class temprecipeapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    temprecipeapp().run()
```